# Meaning of the proverb

Tags: meaning

Meaning of the English proverb "Life is to death as pleasure is pain". I came across this phrase on a newspaper.

Answer (score 1):

This is an [anology](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/analogy).

Analogies are often of the form, "A is to B as C is to D". It asserts a correspondence or partial similarity between "Life" with "pleasure" and "death" with "pain".

As far as meaning, one take is that pain interrupts pleasure as death interrupts life, the latter permanently.

Comment: If you want to pursue this more, there is [Stackexchange Philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/)